# Drupal, Views.. how to display views list + complete node, interactively?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

I'm using Views in Drupal to show node teasers. I would like now to show the complete node on the left side of my page, nearby the Views, and update it when the user click on a different teaser (better using AJAX).

what's the best method to implement it. I was considering to use a lightbox, but it a bit complex (a lot of complications... such as parsing the content with javascript again.. etc).

See screenshot: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/72686/viewsAndNode.png

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved using the lightbox, and just removing the html code I don't need from the node template with php if the parameter "lightbox=true" is passed with the link.

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty approach would be to use an iframe to hold the node content. Users would then be able to switch between nodes without reloading the page, which is I assume your goal. I don't think there is away to achieve what you are trying to do with views out of the box. Have you looked into using panels?

Comment: To clarify, mostly for the OP, you're referring to the panels module (http://drupal.org/project/panels), correct?

Comment: what do u mean for OP ? i actually want a clean solution, because i used ightbox so far, the iframe is terrible, it loads javascript files twice, i cannot parse the content, etc..

Answer (score 0):

Here's what might be a clean way to do it, of course in drupal there's always many ways to accomplish things.

Providing the content for the ajax call

- Install the services module
- Setup a service that provides your node as you want it to be displayed

Create the placeholder for your content

- Install the Panels Module
- Create a empty fixed width panel to contain the node you want to load
- Load the view into an adjacent panel

In your controlling view

- Add a PHP view header and use (drupal_add_js('script.js')) to add a custom js file to the page. or add this to a custom module, or even your theme.
- Re-Write your view node links to help put the js events together

Setup your javascript events

- Use add_js to add a custom javascript js file to the page
- In the custom js add an event to the view links that will poll the services module and load the node into the placeholder panel

Comment: If you want to skip the services module there's a tutorial on creating an ajax call back in a custom module here: http://drupal.org/node/42562